# There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xml-serialization

I need for project in my study save to file serialize object list. I first time using serialize. I read many examples and i can't resolve my error. I getting error 'There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`'
This is my class to serialize

```
namespace projekt2
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class wezel : ICloneable
    {
        public Label text {get;set;}
        public Ellipse el {get;set;}
        public int id {get;set;}
        public wezel(Label text, Ellipse el, int id)
        {
            this.text = text;
            this.el = el;
            this.id = id;
        }
        public wezel()
        {
        }
        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }

    }
}
```

List declaration

```
public List <wezel> w= new List<wezel>();
```

And function what i try serialize

```
public void SerializeToXML(MainWindow window, Canvas canvas, int dpi, string filename)
        {
            string mystrXAML = XamlWriter.Save(canvas);
            FileStream filestream = File.Create(filename);
            StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
            streamwriter.Write(mystrXAML);
            streamwriter.Close();
            filestream.Close();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<wezel>)); 
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"wezly.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, w);
            textWriter.Close(); 
        }
```

Some one can now how to fix this error and serialize this list of object wezel?

Comment: I doubt that Label and Ellipse are Serializable.

Comment: If this is serializable how to serialize this?

Comment: @seti You need to show the code for `Label` and `Ellipse` or show us where the classes came from. For a class to be serializeable all of its members must also be serializeable (Unless it implements [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)).